# "Our services aren't available right" message with custom domain on Azure CDN

Tags: azure

I have just setup custom domain for CDN endpoint (for storage static website) but getting this message when navigating to my website using custom domain:

```
Our services aren't available right now
We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.
```

CDN endpoint (.azureedge.net) works fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

purging the CDN endpoint did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I tried to `curl` my website address and saw that it shown the "Our services aren't available right now" message.

The solution for me was seeing that my CDN endpoint had ONLY HTTPS enabled. I assume curl or Emacs's `eww` terminal browser uses http by default and does not follow Azure's redirects. You can enable HTTP by going to [your cdn endpoint] > Origin > Configure Origin.

My domain is HSTS (.dev) and it still works. HSTS is only a browser feature I think.

[image: Azure Portal's page for a CDN endpoint.. The Settings > Origin section is currently shown. The Configure Option button in the section's header is hovered with the mouse]